# Optimal Register Allocation for Dataflow Graphs

Tags: compiler-construction, google-cloud-dataflow, register-allocation

I am wondering if there is an optimal algorithm for register allocation in a **pure dataflow scenario** (or any papers pursuing as much).

The case I am interested in is all [**local register allocation**](https://people.cs.rutgers.edu/%7Efarach/pubs/cc99-tk.pdf) with no `phi` nodes or `CFG` edges.

The optimization questions, as far as I understand it, is how to schedule the instructions s.t the interference graph is as suitable as possible to easy allocation. But haven't found much/anything that hits the nail on the head (aside from [this locked papers](https://www.computer.org/csdl/proceedings-article/edac/1992/00205919/12OmNx4gUws) whose title is intriguing but I can't read)

From looking around, I've found the [Sethi & Ullman Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sethi%E2%80%93Ullman_algorithm) but after implementing it, I've found it's not what I'm looking for.

The closest I've found in [this MCFN](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eseth/papers/koes-pldi2006.pdf) register allocation schema (proposed for global register allocation, but should be applicable to local register allocation).

If anyone knows an algorithm or paper that points to one I would much appreciated.

For reference the best I'm able to do now is use [strahler numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strahler_number) to choose node traversal and breaking ties by total number of children. Then between each iteration scheduling each instruction that ends the live-range of more registers than it creates.

Comment: Can you explain why Sethi Ullman is not what you were looking for? I stumbled across the following article that explains Sethi Ullman very well:  https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~horwitz/CS701-NOTES/5.REGISTER-ALLOCATION.html

Comment: @urutech I think its b.c Sethi Ullman is targeting cases where there are no references between subtrees in the `DFG` which isnt always true. So it ideally handles `r0 = r1 + r2; r3 = r4 + r5; r6 = r7 + r8; r9 = r0 + r3; r10 = r9 + r6` and could allocate that ideally  but stumbles aroudn `r0 = r1 + r2; r3 = r4 + r5; r6 = r2 + r7; ...` i.e it won't catch that by scheduling the `r6 = r2 + r7` first it actually frees up a new register. What I ended up implementing with essentially `Sethi Ullman` with a pass after each change to pop all expressions who shrink the live-range but its not "optimal"

Comment: What you are describing is more like a series of expressions while S-.U. is perfect for single expressions. I would say that the problem you are trying to solve is identical to the register allocation for within a basic block. There are register allocation algorithms described in the article I‘ve linked above.

Comment: @urutech but AFAICT they all address the problem assuming a fixed `live-range` (maybe with splitting/etc..), they don't address how to order the DFG s.t the live-ranges are optimally colorable.